# Prevent jQuery from executing functions assigned to attributes when generating html

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I ran into an issue when generating html through jQuery.

Imagine this scenario:

We iterate over an object and generate a `div` in every iteration, attaching an onclick handler to it that executes a function that was defined in the object:

```
var obj={
    func1: function(){
        console.log('1');
    },
    func2: function(){
        console.log('2');
    }
};
for(var r in obj){
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(r)){
        $('<div/>', {
            class: 'testClass',
            onclick: obj[r]
        }).appendTo('#main');
    }
}
```

The problem is that the function is being executed when it is applied to `onclick`. I tried wrapping it in a proxy function, but then it is the proxy function which gets executed, thus yielding the same results.

How can i apply the functions defined in the object to the `onclick` handler, without them being executed?

[See the according jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3LRjM/)

(You will notice that on load (when defining the object and then running through the iterations, the functions will get executed, thus you will see '1' and '2' printed in the console log)

Comment: they didn't execute when i pasted your code in my chrome console...

Comment: Try the fiddle. I use chrome for development. The issue is reproducible at a 100% success rate. Brian's solution however does work perfectly, although i still don't understand why jQuery executes the functions during assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind event handlers using jQuery instead of using the onclick attribute:

> `for(var r in obj){
>       if(obj.hasOwnProperty(r)){
>           $('<div/>', {
>               class: 'testClass'
>           }).on('click', obj[r]).appendTo('#main');
>       }
>   }`

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3LRjM/1/).

Comment: Ah! Very obvious, i totally missed that possibility. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because u are using `onclick` instead of using `click` jQuery tends to execute the `onclick` property rather than applying it as a click handler try this fiddle it should work now

`var obj={
        func1: function(){
            console.log('1');
        },
        func2: function(){
            console.log('2');
        },
    };
    for(var r in obj){
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(r)){
            $('<div/>', {
                class: 'testClass',
                click: obj[r]
            }).appendTo('#main');
        }
    }`
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chhetrisushil/3LRjM/3/)

Comment: +1 for explaining why it happens and providing an alternative. However, Brian's approach is probably the more suitable and more clean one, so i'll stick to his answer. Thank you for collaborating.